# Verifying if the password field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form in which the user enters the username and the password in an attempt to login to his profile. I want to dynamically verify that both the fields are filled before i start doing the server side processing.

---

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="student.jsp">

          <label><strong>Username :</strong><br/><br/>
          <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="idusername">
        </label><br/><br/>

          <label><strong>Password :</strong><br/><br/>
          <input type="text" value="" name="password" id="idpassword">
            </label><br/><br/><br/>

          <input id="minibutton" name="send" type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
```

---

I am using javascript which correctly verifies and alerts whenever the username is left blank and we attempt to login. However, it does not do so with the password field and we can get away with it being left blank.

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//global vars
var form = $("#form");
var username= $("#idusername");
var password = $("idpassword");

//On Submitting
form.submit(function(){
    if(username.val().length==0 || password.val().length==0){
                    alert('Please enter the username');
        return false;
                    }
    else
    {
                if(password.val().length==0)
                    {
                        alert('Please enter the password');
                        return false;
                    }

                 else   
                    return true;
    }
});
});
```

---

I am not good at javascript but i need to use it for dynamic validation. Plaese pointy out the error in verifying the password field.

Answer (score 6):

The missing hash symbol:

```
var password = $("idpassword");
```

should be:

```
var password = $("#idpassword");
```

Answer (score 4):

change `var password = $("idpassword");` to `var password = $("#idpassword");`

Answer (score 1):

also in your logic:

```
if(username.val().length==0 || password.val().length==0){
    alert('Please enter the username');
    return false;
}
else{
    if(password.val().length==0)
    {
        alert('Please enter the password');
        return false;
    }
    else   
        return true;
}
```

if either the user name or password is empty, its always going to say "please enter the username" as it matches the if clause,

you should change it to 2 if's

```
if(username.val().length==0){
    alert('Please enter the username');
    return false;
}
if(password.val().length==0){
    alert('Please enter the password');
    return false;
}
return true;
```

That way, it checks if the user name is filled, then if the password is filled, if they both are, return true, else, if one is empty, it will flag it being empty and return false.

Hope this helps